# Put User-Interaction in the process of UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, email, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a problem. I want to mail some data either in the form of exce or csv or pdf.
The Flow is , I have to present an UIActivityViewController. The I Have to click on the mail button. Then activity view controller should disappear. Then a view will came (made by me) that will ask about the format of file which i have to mail. Then next the mail view will open asking about the email address etc. The i will click send and it will sent.

My problem is:- I am using UIActivityViewController but i dont know how to stop its process as i click on mail and put some user interaction in between.

Please Help.

Comment: Do you want to show only Mail option in your UIActivityViewController?

Comment: Seems that there isn't api for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the activityDidFinish: method on the chosen UIActivity.

From the docs for UIActivity activityDidFinish::

Comment: Hey, Thanks for reply,But here i am talking about the UIActivityViewController not UIActivity.